# How do I get the values from my while loop into my echo table?

Tags: php, while-loop, html-table, echo

I'm pretty new to programming, especially PHP so my question probably is the wrong way to go about things. Essentially I have a range of numbers, generated using a conditional loop, which have to be input into an echo table.

```
$numbers=30;
while ($numbers<=40)
{
if($numbers%2==0) {echo " " . $numbers . "<br />";;}
else {;}
$numbers++;
}

echo " <table border='1'>
<tr>
<td>Rectangle 1 <br> $numbers </td>
</tr>
</table>";
```

There is other stuff in the table, and I don't want the entire table to loop, so basically I'm wondering how I would get the whole list of values, from my while loop, into the table.

Comment: You could create a variable to hold the value of the printed numbers, or you could echo part of the table before the loop, and the rest after. Also, it's not required to have an else block, so if it's empty, you can just leave it out. If you are going to leave it empty, you don't need a semicolon in it. And lastly, in PHP, you can use variables inside string literals with double quotes: `echo " $numbers<br/>"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one For table formate data

```
$numbers=30;
echo " <table border='1'>";
while ($numbers<=40)
{
if($numbers%2==0) {
 echo "<tr><td>Rectangle 1 <br> $numbers </td></tr>";
 }
else {;}
$numbers++;
}
echo "</table>";
```

This may helpful to you!!!!